# How do I write a method for multiple controllers that strips out an array of text?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string-substitution

I want to write a method that simplifies the names of corporations.  I would like it to work as follows:

```
@clear_company = clear_company(@company.name)
```

What would happen is @company.name = "Company, Inc."  @clear_company would be "Company"

If @company.name = "Company Corporation" @clear_company would be "Company"

There wouldn't be extra spaces.  I looked at different strip and gsub, but I need to maintain an array:

```
clean_array = %w[Inc. Incorporated LLC]
```

I could update that to make it more effective.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in lib/clear_company.rb:

```
 module ClearCompany
  BUSINESS_ENTITY = %w[Corporation Inc. Incorporated LLC]

  def clear_company
    strip_business_entity.remove_trailing_punctuation
  end

  def strip_business_entity
    BUSINESS_ENTITY.inject(self) do |company, clean_word|
      company.sub(clean_word, '')
    end
  end

  def remove_trailing_punctuation
    strip.sub(/,$/, '')
  end
end
```

in config/initializers/string.rb:

```
class String
  include ClearCompany
end
```

if you like RSpec:

```
describe String, :clear_company do
  it "removes ', Inc.' from the end" do
    "Company, Inc.".clear_company.should == "Company"
  end

  it "removes ' Corporation' from the end" do
    "Company Corporation".clear_company.should == "Company"
  end
end
```

Comment: yeah I would have extended String as well

Comment: where do I extend the String class?  do I put in config/initializers/clear_company.rb file?

Comment: I'd extract the behavior above into `lib/clear_company.rb` as a module and then monkey patch String in `config/initializers/string.rb` to simply `include ClearCompany`

Comment: I see...so the code in clear_company.rb in the /lib would still be the same as above, and then I apply the patch to string.rb?

Comment: hi so would I still use it as described clear_company(company.name) or is it company.name.clear_company?

Comment: You see that the spec `"Company, Inc.".clear_company.should == "Company"` is an example of sending the message `clear_company` to a String and the expected outcome.  I've introduced RSpec to a number of people, some get it immediately, but for others the language doesn't come right away.  I get the impression that they expect the code to be less readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
def clear_company(name)
  clean_array = %w[Inc. Incorporated LLC]
  name = name.strip
  word_to_remove = clean_array.find {|x| name[/#{x}$/] }
  name.sub(/#{word_to_remove}$/, '').strip
end
```

The `.strip` at the end is important because without it, "X Inc." would become "X ".

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning data is **not really a concern of the controller**, so **its best keep it in the model**. The easiest way is using a `before_save` filter:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :clean_name

private
  def clean_name
    self.name = name.gsub(/Corporation|LLC|Incorporated|Inc.?/i, "").strip
  end 
end
```